# check if user logged in firebase python

Tags: python, firebase-authentication, logout

im using firebase as my database in kivy project,I wanted to display main screen if a user is already logged in otherwise the login screen. How can i know if the person is logged in or out using python firebase api
this is my code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.toast import toast
import firebase_admin
from firebase import Firebase
from firebase_admin import credentials,auth
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate("C:/Users/RAJAT/Downloads/fir-50c26-firebase-adminsdk-rwle3-a9063a3375.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{'databaseURL':'https://fir-50c26.firebaseio.com/'})

config={
            'apiKey':'AIzaSyCuvad-ZHHXVRp1Ly3AyOwgpPgG1zi-wJs',
            'authDomain':'fir-50c26.firebaseapp.com',
            'databaseURL':'https://fir-50c26.firebaseio.com/',
            'storageBucket':'fir-50c26.appspot.com',
            'serviceAccount':'C:/Users/RAJAT/Downloads/fir-50c26-firebase-adminsdk-rwle3-a9063a3375.json'
}
fb=Firebase(config)
au=fb.auth()

class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def login(self):
        uid = self.root.ids.username.text
        pas = self.root.ids.password.text
        try:
            hi=au.sign_in_with_email_and_password(uid,pas)
            self.root.current = 's3'
            print(hi)
            print('success')
        except Exception as e:
            e=str(e)
            e=e.split(':')
            e=e[6]
            e=e.split(',')[0]
            toast(e)

    def signup(self):
        usn=self.root.ids.User.text
        email=self.root.ids.Email.text
        phone=self.root.ids.Phone.text
        phone='+91'+phone
        pas=self.root.ids.Pass.text
        try:
            self.usr = auth.create_user(uid=usn, display_name=usn,phone_number=phone, email=email,password=pas)
        except Exception as err:
            err=str(err)
            toast(err)

    def signedinorno(self):
        uid='raj'
        user=auth.get_user(uid)
        ar=au.get_account_info(user['idToken'])



DemoApp().run()
```

here i have used 2 api because python_firebase doesn't provide login option i guess, because i didnt get it in documentation.here is the link for the libraries that i have used,
firebase_admin:
https://pypi.org/project/firebase-admin/
and the api used for login is,
firebase:
https://pypi.org/project/firebase/

Comment: Can you provide a link to the  "python firebase api" you're using?

Comment: Those are two separate libraries. Which one are you using? It might help if we see the code of how you currently already interact with Firebase.

Comment: can you suggest any other API that i can use for this issue

Comment: The Firebase Admin SDKs don't have the logic to sign in a user, as they don't have concept of a current user. This is normally left to the client-side application, with the Admin SDK then getting the ID token from the client and verifying that it is valid. Unfortunately the comment with the links to the libraries is gone, so can you edit your question to include the link to the library that implements `au.sign_in_with_email_and_password(uid,pas)`?